# 3 step ODE method using interpolating polynomial

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I am trying to find a 3-step method of the form $y_{i+1}=y_{i-2}+b_0f_{i-2}+b_1f_{i-1}+b_2f_i$ to solve the ODE $y'=f(t,y)$ by using an interpolating polynomial and then finding 
$\int_0^{3h} f(t,y(t)) dy$ in the form $b_0f_{i-2}+b_1f_{i-1}+b_2f_i+...$

Using the Lagrange coefficient, I have found the interpolating polynomial to be 
$$\frac{(t-t_{i-1})(t-t_{i-2})}{(t_i-t_{i-1})(t_i-t_{i-2})}f_i+\frac{(t-t_i)(t-t_{i-2})}{(t_{i-1}-t_{i})(t_{i-1}-t_{i-2})}f_{i-1}+\frac{(t-t_{i-1})(t-t_i)}{(t_{i-2}-t_{i-1})(t_{i-2}-t_i)}f_{i-2}$$
Assuming step size is equal, so $t_i-t_{i-1}=h$ for all i, this can be simplified to:
$$\frac{(t-t_{i-1})(t-t_{i-2})}{2h^2}f_i+\frac{(t-t_i)(t-t_{i-2})}{h^2}f_{i-1}+\frac{(t-t_{i-1})(t-t_i)}{2h^2}f_{i-2}$$

Now putting this into the integral:
$$\int_0^{3h}\frac{(t-t_{i-1})(t-t_{i-2})}{2h^2}f_i+\frac{(t-t_i)(t-t_{i-2})}{h^2}f_{i-1}+\frac{(t-t_{i-1})(t-t_i)}{2h^2}f_{i-2}dy$$

My problem now is integrating this. How can I integrate $f$ with respect to $y$? I considered splitting the interval into 
$$\int_0^{3h}f(t,y(t))dy=\int_0^hf(t,y(t))dy+\int_h^{2h}f(t,y(t))dy+\int_{2h}^{3h}f(t,y(t))dy$$
and allowing $y(0)=\alpha$, $y(h)=\beta$, $y(2h)=\gamma$, but I am stuck after this point.

Would it be a good idea to substitute $y'(t)=f(t,y(t))$ into the polynomial to be integrated, despite needing a solution in terms of $f_i$, $f_{i-1}$ and $f_{i-2}$?

EDIT: So integrating with respect to y is illogical. How would I integrate with respect to t instead? I thought I'd have to use $t_{i-1}$ and $t_i$ or $t_i$ and $t_{i+1}$ as limits rather than $0$ and $h$, as how will the $t_i$ terms simplify?

Comment: Try integrating with respect to $t$. That is what I would do, but I am not an expert in numerical methods.

Comment: The problem is that then the limits don't make sense.

Comment: $y$ is the unknown function. It does not make sense to integrate with repeat to it. $f(t,y(t))$ is a function of $t$.